# VRML is not asoriginal after loading using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, vrml

i'm trying to load VRML models using VRMLLoader from three.js (here is a link: http://cadcamge.ch/lasha/vrmlviewer/) and have some problems with colors cause every surface has different color i want to load as solid this [Three.js - VRML Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636220/three-js-vrml-loader) isn't solution for me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution cited is correct, why would that not work for you?

Alternatively, make sure your input VRML has explicit color specifications

Comment: That function turns whole screen red, when i zoom out there is sphere around the object,  which has same color as model and i get picture where this sphere and object is red and background is black.